# Does cloning in angular-dragdrop work?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-droppable

The angular-dragdrop examples contain the following example:

["Shopping card with cloning"](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/cart)

Only it doesn't clone.
And it seems to be a reimplementation of this example:

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

Which does clone.

So is the takeaway that this functionality just doesn't exist in angular-dragdrop?

Answer (score 5):

In order to enable cloning you need to set

```
jqyoui-draggable="{placeholder:'keep'}"
```

AND

```
data-jqyoui-options="{helper:'clone'}"
```

without the helper cloning doesn't work.

If you take a look at the example's code (http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/cart) you will see that he sets both attributes. Unfortunately it isn't mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [angular-dragon-drop](https://github.com/btford/angular-dragon-drop) which supports cloning.